# Prevent application from being killed on rooted device

Tags: android, root

I am working for an company witch wants to give employes devices that can track them using gps. I want to create a service that won't close in task manager.

Is this possible ?

Comment: If its your company's private device and they customized android OS for this application then its possible..

Comment: @PoweRoy why not? It may be a transport company.

Comment: @PoweRoy is a company witch distributes flyers and needs to monitor employes in the time of duty.Data isn't collected after a certain hour ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be implementing a System Service on the device. These are apps which are started on boot and stopped at shutdown. The user won't be able to stop these.

However you will need rooted device with modified Android OS software.

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449390501/Android_System_Services.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its possible. Any non-system process/app running in android can be killed/stopped. Your best bet would be to restart that service in case it got killed.

Answer (score -1):

From ICS onwards, any app implementing [Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) cannot be stopped. This is being done for specifically for enterprise customers to have this option. Further you do not even need root access for this.

Comment: Yeah but user can deselect Device Administator option from settings and disable that setting.

Comment: then you should not run your app. It is like if someone wants to use the app then it should be on. Like every time they disable you can wipe the device, since its a enterprise device ,this should be acceptable. People will think before they disable

Comment: I tested this in Android 4.3, and my app's service was still killed when the phone got low on memory despite the app's device administrator being enabled.

Comment: the answer was specifically for ways to prevent user from force stopping